# How to escape writers block

Tags: creative-writing, novel, writers-block

I've written things for an audience before, but I've never written a small novel like I currently am planning.

I haven't wrote anything since maybe December of last year so I am very rusty on my work. I've been in writer's block for months and can't seem to escape it. I've tried doing the things I've used to like lighting candles and creating a nice atmosphere, listening to music and whatnot. But nothing seems to be working.

I've planned out most of the characters, the plot, the setting and world that I'm going to write about, but whenever I attempt to write everything just seems to vanish. I'm not expecting to get paragraphs of people telling me exactly what to write but maybe some of you have experienced what I am and know of a way to help push me out of this. Thanks in advanced.